# Rails Routes :shallow => true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Wondering why my /articles route is not coming up when I apply :shallow => true?

routes.rb

```
resources :users, :shallow => true do
  resources :articles
end
```

Also tried this:

```
resources :users do
  resources :articles, :shallow => true
end
```

Visiting /articles won't show me all articles from any user as expected, but I can still visit /articles/:id just fine. Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `shallow: true` option does not provide an index resource according to [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources). Therefore, you will not be able to access just `/articles`. So yes, this is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - anything with an ID (`show`, `edit`, `update`, `destroy`) doesn't need a parent to identify itself.

The other two (`create`, `index`), need the parent to scope the query.

You would need to create another resource

```
resources :articles, :only => [:index]
```

To see all articles